# Using mixin in scss file

Tags: scss-mixins

I have a file default.scss and in the file I have this css

```
        .excelGridCell { 
            background: $nav-background;
            height: 2.5em;
            border-radius: .8rem;
        }
```

I created a mixin in the same file like this because I want to use mixin to be able to reuse this css.

```
        @mixin special-button {
            .excelGridCell {
                background: $nav-background;
                height: 2.5em;
                border-radius: .8rem;
            }
        }
```

Then called it in the same file(default.scss) like this.

```
        .excelGridCell{
            @include special-button
        }
```

This does not work. Is this the right way to use mixin with scss ?

Comment: what do you mean by "this does not work"? Is there an error somewhere?

Comment: The css I applied does not show up when my page loads.

Comment: if sass doesn't report any errors you can look at the .css file it generates, and see if all classes there appear as expected. That might give you some clues to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a class selector in your mixin.

That's why it's not applied.

```
@mixin special-button {
    background: $nav-background;
    height: 2.5em;
    border-radius: .8rem;
}
```

Change your mixin to the above and it will work. You almost had it. The way your selector would work based on the code you wrote would look for an element with class="excelGridCell" and then a nested element with a class="excelGridCell".

Also, I usually only use mixins for something that needs a parameter (potentially with a default value).

For this use case, you may want to just use @extend with some inheritance.

See section "Extend/Inheritance"

in https://sass-lang.com/guide

however this might be a bit of a religious war
https://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can implement mixin in your scss file:**

```
@mixin mobile-md {
  @media (min-width: #{$breakpoint-mobile + 80}) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

**And this is how you can use it in your code:**

```
@include mobile-md {
  // Styles for screens larger than the mobile-md breakpoint
}
```

**Let's understand all about mixin:**

The provided code snippet is written in SCSS (Sassy CSS) and defines a mixin called **mobile-md**. A mixin in SCSS is a reusable block of code that can be included in other stylesheets using the **@include** directive.

**Here's a breakdown of what the code does:**

`@mixin mobile-md { ... }`: This line defines a mixin named `mobile-md`.

`@media (min-width: #{$breakpoint-mobile + 80}) { ... }`: This line specifies a media query that targets a minimum width equal to the value of the variable `$breakpoint-mobile` plus 80. The `min-width` condition is used to apply the styles within the media query only if the viewport width meets the specified criteria.

`@content;`: This line is a placeholder that will be replaced with the actual content of the mixin when it is included in other stylesheets using `@include`.

To better understand the code, we need to know the value of the variable `$breakpoint-mobile`. It seems that the value of this variable is expected to be a number representing a specific mobile breakpoint. The mixin `mobile-md` is intended to apply styles when the viewport width is larger than the mobile breakpoint plus 80 pixels.

**By utilizing the mobile-md mixin with appropriate styles inside the @media block, you can create responsive designs that adapt to different screen sizes.**

[image]